# Help please, React State is not changing, when trying to fetch account balance

Tags: metamask, ethers.js, react

**I am trying to fetch the account balance as seen below I have highlighted the h2 tag (below with ////////// ) for retrieving account balance, but when I console.log(this.state), I getting the predefined values and not able to get the changed state**

```
      import logo from './logo.svg';
        import './App.css';
        import bodyImage from "./main-image.png";
        import React, { Component } from 'react'
        
        const {ethers,Contract,providers}=require("ethers")
        
        class App extends Component {
        
        constructor(){
          super()
          this.state={
            defaultAccount:null,
            addressClick:true,
            aggregatContract:null,
            daiContract:null,
            cDaiContract:null,
            AaveLendingPoolContract:null,
            ethers:null,
            walletBalance:"5",
            aggregatorBalance:null,
            location:null,
            dai_address: "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F",
            cDAI_address: "0x5d3a536E4D6DbD6114cc1Ead35777bAB948E3643",
            aaveLendingPool_address: "0x7d2768dE32b0b80b7a3454c06BdAc94A69DDc7A9"
        
          }
        
        
        }
        
        
        componentWillMount() {
          this.loadWindow()
        }
        
        async loadWindow(){
          if(window.ethereum){
            await window.ethereum.request({method:'eth_requestAccounts'}).then((result)=>{
              this.setState({defaultAccount:result[0]})
              this.setState({addressClick:false})
              this.setState({ethers:ethers})
              //window.alert("Wallet Connected")
        
            })
            await this.loadWeb3Data()
        
          }else{
            window.alert("No ethereum account detected...")
          }
        }
        
        
        
        async loadWeb3Data(){
        
          const AggregatorAbi=[
            "function deposit(uint256 fund, uint256 _aveAPY, uint256 _compAPY) public",
            "function Withdraw() public onlyOwner",
            "function whereBalance() public view returns(address)",
            "function ContractBalance() public view returns(uint256)",
            "function reBalance( uint256 _aveAPY, uint256 _compAPY ) public onlyOwner"
          ]
          const daiAbi=[
            "function approve(address usr, uint wad) external returns (bool)",
            " function transfer(address dst, uint wad) external returns (bool)",
            "function transferFrom(address src, address dst, uint wad) public returns (bool)",
            "function balanceOf(address) external view returns (uint256)"
          ]
        
          const cDaiAbi=[
            "function mint(uint256) external returns (uint256)",
            "function redeem(uint256) external returns (uint256)",
            "function supplyRatePerBlock() external returns (uint256)",
            " function balanceOf(address) external view returns (uint256)"
          ]
          const AaveLendingPoolAbi=[
        
            "function deposit(address asset,uint256 amount,address onBehalfOf,uint16 referralCode) external",
            "function withdraw(address asset,uint256 amount,address to) external"
          ]
        
          
         const provider=new providers.Web3Provider(window.ethereum)
          //const aggregatContract = await Contract("0x42b71288FE55B1a3857Ecc1B28614Cf56272aDE7",AggregatorAbi);
          //this.setState({aggregatContract});
          window.alert("Start")
          const daiContract=new Contract("0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F",daiAbi,provider);
        
           this.setState({daiContract:daiContract})
        
          const cDaiContract= new Contract("0x5d3a536E4D6DbD6114cc1Ead35777bAB948E3643",cDaiAbi,provider)
           this.setState({cDaiContract:cDaiContract})
        
          const AaveLendingPoolContract=new Contract("0x7d2768dE32b0b80b7a3454c06BdAc94A69DDc7A9",AaveLendingPoolAbi,provider)
           this.setState({AaveLendingPoolContract:AaveLendingPoolContract})
        
        await this.fetchAccountInfo()
        
        }
        
        
        async fetchAccountInfo(){
        console.log(this.state)
        
        let walletBalance=await this.state.daiContract.balanceOf(this.state.defaultAccount)
         console.log(this.state)
        
          window.alert("stop")
        
          //let aggregatorBalance =await this.state.aggregatContract.amountDeposited()
        
            walletBalance = this.state.ethers.utils.formatEther(walletBalance, 'ether')
                //aggregatorBalance = this.state.ethers.utils.formatEther(aggregatorBalance, 'ether')
        
            this.setState({walletBalance:walletBalance});
            //this.setState({aggregatorBalance:aggregatorBalance});
        
            //const activelocation= this.state.aggregatContract.balanceWhere();
            //activelocation===this.state.aaveLendingPool_address? this.setState({location:"Aave lending platform"}):this.setState({location:"Compound Platform"});
            
        }
        
        
          render() {
            return (
              <div className="App">
        
             <div className="Navbar">
               <h4 className='Text'>Aggregator Rebalancer</h4>
                <div  className="Address">
                {this.state.addressClick?<button type="button" className='Connect'>Connect Wallet</button>:<h4>{this.state.defaultAccount}</h4>}
                </div>
             </div>
        
             <div className='Body-component'>
             <div className="Heading">
              <h1>Funds Rebalancer</h1>
             </div>
        
             <center><img className='Diag' src={bodyImage} alt="blockchain" /></center>
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

         ===>>>**<h2>{this.state.walletBalance}</h2>**<<<===

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
         <div className="InputData">
         <form className='Data' onSubmit={(e) => {
                                        e.preventDefault()
                                    }}>
                                        <input type="number" placeholder="Amount"/>
                                        <button type="submit" className="Button">Deposit</button>
                      <button type="submit" className="Button">Rebalance</button>
                      <button type="submit" className="Button">Withdraw</button>
                                    </form>
         </div>
         <div className="Text">
    
         </div>
        </div>
        </div>
        )
      }
    }
    
    
    
    export default App;
```

Comment: I see a few issues with this code. First, try to set the state once with all the values you need. Don't chain a setState after another. ex: `this.setState({ obj1: 'foo', obj2: 'bar', etc: 'etc...' })` in your code above you are calling `setState()` one after another. This could be one of your main issues. And call setState after your promises resolve. I think you're having problems because your component is rendering before your promises resolve.

Comment: Thank you, I will change the this.setState from now on, thanks for that. But even I have noticed that component is rendering before the promise resolve, but I had used await for all the promise so that only after they resolved as you can see the code above then I can change the state. please suggest me if I am wrong.